# game theory question

Tags: game-theory

For a non-cooperative bimatrix game the feasible set is

$$\{(u,v)=(\mathbf{p}^TA \mathbf{q},\mathbf{p}^TB \mathbf{q}):p \in X^*, q \in Y^*\}$$

graph the non-cooperative feasible set for the Battle of the Sexes with bimatrix,

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}(2,1)&(0,0)\\(0,0)&(1,2)\end{array}\right)$$

My thoughts:

When I calculated $\mathbf{p}^T A \mathbf{q}$ I get $3pq-p-q+1$.. If I set this equal to 0 the graph is a hyperbola.  It is similar for $\mathbf{p}^T B \mathbf{q}$..  However, I don't think I am on the right track, and not really sure the interpretation.  Game theory is still quite new to me.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: Rather than setting things equal to zero, let p and q run over the range from 0 to 1, independently, and graph that.  So for example, (2,1) is in the feasible set, as is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Plot the payoff profiles (2,1), (0,0) and (1,2) in two-dimensional payoff space. The convex hull of these points is the set of feasible payoffs under (correlated) mixed strategies.